# How do I create a new record in Android Room database?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

This seems like a lazy question, but the offical docs literally don't explain how to do this.

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

I have an entity like so:

```
@Entity
data class Shader(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val uid: Int,
    val name: String,
    val shaderMainText: String,
    val paramsJson: String?
)
```

And some methods on my `Dao`:

```
    @Insert
    fun insertAll(vararg shaders: Shader)

    @Delete
    fun delete(shader: Shader)

    @Update
    fun update(shader: Shader)
```

How do I make a new record and insert it?

I've gotten so far as this:

```
val record = Shader(name="Foo", shaderMainText="bar", paramsJson=null)
```

But it complains that I'm missing the argument `uid`. Why do I need to provide a `uid`? It's supposed to be auto-generated?

An example of creating a new record would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe, this can help https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin#5

Comment: @Javlon it doesn't. That page tells you how to make a DAO. I already have one. I want a code example of how to actually create a new record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `0` for the default value of your `uid` field

```kotlin
@Entity
data class Shader(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val uid: Int = 0,
    val name: String,
    val shaderMainText: String,
    val paramsJson: String?
)
```

When `autoGenerate` is `true`, Room ignores the default value, so it creates auto-incremented values.
Finally, this doesn't give you a compilation error:

```kotlin
val record = Shader(name="Foo", shaderMainText="bar", paramsJson=null)
```

Comment: Room only ignores the default value if it is 0 or null (if nullable). Both are considered special cases, 0 is only ignored if autoGenerate is true and generates the SQL without a value for the respective column. Null is ignored whether or not autoGenerate=true or not (either explicitly with false being coded, or implicitly if the parameter is omitted). So Int=100 will result in the value stored being 100 (or not if the value already exists in another row).

Answer (score 1):

The docs say:

> If the field type is long or int (or its TypeConverter converts it to a long or int), Insert methods treat 0 as not-set while inserting the item.

> If the field's type is Integer or Long (or its TypeConverter converts it to an Integer or a Long), Insert methods treat null as not-set while inserting the item.

So I would try setting the uid to be initialized to 0 or make it nullable and set to null.

Hope that helps!

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/PrimaryKey#autoGenerate()

Answer (score 0):

**You Can Also try like this**

The best practice is you always create an `instance` Class

- 1st Create a Database instance class

  ```
   @Database(entities = [Shader::class], version = 1)
   abstract class DatabaseHelper : RoomDatabase() {

  companion object {
   private var instance: DatabaseHelper? = null
   fun getInstance(context: Context?): DatabaseHelper? {
       if (instance == null) {
           synchronized(DatabaseHelper::class) {
               if (context != null) {
                   instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, DatabaseHelper::class.java, "database.db").allowMainThreadQueries().build()
               }
           }

       }
       return instance
   }
  }

  abstract fun getDao(): DBDao?

  }
  ```
- Create Your `Shader` `data class` like below

  ```
     @Entity(tableName = "shader")
     data class Shader(
     @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Int?,
     val name: String,
     val shaderMainText: String,
     val paramsJson: String?
     ) {
          constructor(name: String, shaderMainText: String, paramsJson: String?) : this(
   null,
   name,
   shaderMainText,
   paramsJson
   )
  }
  ```

  Here you want to create `constructor`
- Add data in `Shader` and `insertAll` Like Below

  ```
   val record = Shader(name="Foo", shaderMainText="bar", paramsJson=null)
   DatabaseHelper.getInstance(this)?.getDao()?.insertAll(record)
  ```

And Your Data added is successfully

[image]

Answer (score -1):

There should be always a  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false) while inserting data in the DB

Comment: Hi Ekta, I'm asking for a code example of how to do this. Your answer does not provide that.